# Could video be considered as a valid halachic witness in court?

Tags: halacha, technology, beit-din-court, edim-witnesses

My understanding is that court cases require a minimum of two witnesses to testify against someone.

Could one of these witnesses be a video, or does it need to be specifically a live human? Would there be any difference if the case was monetary or criminal such as a murder trial?

Answer (score 4):

In an [article](http://matzav.com/body-cams-and-viral-videos-the-halachic-implications-of-video-technology/) about using video as witnesses, Rabbi Micha Cohen writes the following:

> The Mishpetai Uziel (CM 14) marginalizes the approach of Rabbi Abuhav and the Chid”a. He points out that the Rambam writes that seeing a reflection is disqualified because ‘this is not seeing’. The simple reading of the Rambam indicates that the Torah requires seeing the actual moon, not its reflection. He maintains that this is the mainstream approach. For this reason he writes that pictures or recordings are not valid testimony in Bais Din. **While they may be accurate, the Torah requires the witnesses to have seen the actual situation.**

See the full article [here](http://matzav.com/body-cams-and-viral-videos-the-halachic-implications-of-video-technology/), for more clarity.

It seems from the article that any situation that would require a witness to have *seen* the things happen, in that case a video is not enough even if the case is a monetary one.

Comment: Any comments from the downvoter?